# How to call UnitySendMessage to an interface method

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins

Working on Android Plugin for Unity.

To communicate from Android to Unity I use [UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(string s1,string s2, string s3)](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html), this method takes as parameters three strings:

1. s1: GameObject name that will receive the message.
2. s2: Name of the Method that will handle the message.
3. s3: The message.

So this setup works, on my android plugin I use the follow code to send the message to my UnityClass:

`UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName", "OnResult", results);`

In Unity, my GameObject with the name "GameObjectName" implements the method:

`private void OnResult(string recognizedResult);`

**Now it comes the trouble**

Now I want that this GameObject class implements an interface to make it mandatory the handling of the "OnResult".

BUT if I create the following interface:

```
//Interface for MonoBehaviour plugin holder
public interface IPlugin
{
    void OnResult(string recognizedResult);
}
```

And then on my MonoBehaviour class I implement the interface so it looks like:

```
void IPlugin.OnResult(string recognizedResult)
```

This approach seems to do not work. I've  tried to call UnitySendMessage with both `"OnResult"` and `"IPlugin.OnResult"`, neither works.

I'm doing something wrong? Or it's just a limitation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can [implement interfaces explicitely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) like you just did, or implicitly. It seems that Unity only recognises the method when its implemented Implicitly.

```
interface IPlugin
{
    void OnResult(string recognizedResult);

}

class Working : IPlugin
{
    public void OnResult(string recognizedResult)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class NoWorking : IPlugin
{
    void IPlugin.OnResult(string recognizedResult)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```